# What causes dask job failure with CancelledError exception

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have been seeing below error message for quite some time now but could not figure out what leads to the failure.

Error:

```
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: ('sort_index-f23b0553686b95f2d91d4a3fda85f229', 7)
```

On restart of dask cluster it runs successfully.

Comment: could you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or some more context on your workflow to help diagnose the issue? Was @elukem 's answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If running a `dask-cloudprovider` `ECSCluster` or `FargateCluster` the `concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError` can result from a long-running step in computation where there is no output (logging or otherwise) to the `Client`. In these cases, due to the lack of interaction with the client, the scheduler regards itself as "idle" and times out after the configured `cloudprovider.ecs.scheduler_timeout` period, which defaults to 5 minutes. The CancelledError error message is misleading, but if you look in the logs for the scheduler task itself it will record the idle timeout.

The solution is to set `scheduler_timeout` to a higher value, either via config or by passing directly to the `ECSCluster`/`FargateCluster` constructor.